# How to fix Xst:528 this signal is connected to multiple drivers

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx, xilinx-ise

I am receiving this error in my code,I think this error arises when we try to assign a variable different values in multiple always blocks,but in my case i am not doing so,but still receiving this error.

ERRORS:

```
 Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><0>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><1>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><2>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><3>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><6>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><7>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><0>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><1>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><2>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><3>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><6>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><7>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><0>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><1>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><2>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><3>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><6>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><7>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><0>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><1>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><2>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><3>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><6>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><7>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><0>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><1>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><2>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><3>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><6>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><7>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><0>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><1>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><2>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><3>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><6>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><7>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><0>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><1>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><2>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><3>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><6>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><7>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><0>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><1>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><2>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><3>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><6>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><7>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><0>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><1>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><2>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><3>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><6>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><7>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><0>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><1>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><2>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><3>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><6>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><7>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><0>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><1>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><2>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><3>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><6>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><7>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><0>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><1>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><2>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><3>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><6>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><7>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><0>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><1>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><2>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><3>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><6>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><7>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><0>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><1>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><2>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><3>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><6>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><7>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><0>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><1>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><2>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><3>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><6>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><7>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><0>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><1>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><2>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><3>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><6>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><7>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><0>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><1>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><2>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><3>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><6>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><7>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><0>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><1>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><2>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><3>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><6>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><7>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><0>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><1>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><2>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><3>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><6>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><7>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><0>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><1>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><2>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><3>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><6>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<1><7>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><4>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Output_calc_debug> on signal <oc_out<3><5>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
```

Module Code:

```
module Output_calc_debug(
 input clk,
input wire signed [0:7]oc_in,
input [0:2]pid,
output reg signed[0:31]oc_out_1d);


//Mapping 1D I/O list to 2d local vars
reg signed[0:7]oc_out[0:3];


always @(oc_out[0],oc_out[1],oc_out[2],oc_out[3])
begin
oc_out_1d[0:7]=oc_out[0];
oc_out_1d[8:15]=oc_out[1];
oc_out_1d[16:23]=oc_out[2];
oc_out_1d[24:31]=oc_out[3];
end

/***code***/


always @ (posedge clk)
begin :OC_block


    if(oc_in[0:1]==2'd0)
    begin

        cr_x<=oc_in[4:5]/2;
        cr_y<=oc_in[4:5]%2;
        dr_x<=oc_in[6:7]/2;
        dr_y<=oc_in[6:7]%2;

        /***code***/

        if(cr_y<dr_y) 
        begin
            cr_y<=cr_y+2'b1; 
oc_out[E]=oc_in;
oc_out[E][4:5]=(cr_x * 2) + cr_y;
path<=E;    
        end


/***code***/
```

> Note: I am using oc_out variable as a 2d array for putting data into
>   my 1d array oc_out_1d[as verilog doesn't support 2d arrays in i/o
>   list] and updating my output variable in one always block and my 2d
>   local array in another always block.

Comment: It is complaining about `oc_out` reg bits being drive more than once. This is a hard bug. I guess that you are missing a part of the code in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You omitted important code. One assignment is here:

oc_out[E]=oc_in; 
   oc_out[E][4:5]=(cr_x * 2) + cr_y;

But we can't see what E is or where it comes from. Looking at your error messages E is probably a loop variable.

Also that is a non-blocking assignment in a clocked section. Is that om purpose?

You can use 2d ports in system Verilog which is supported in latest Xilinx tools.